# Run ActiveMQ Artemis and connected clients in separate JDK versions

Tags: activemq-artemis

Are there any issues with running ActiveMQ Artemis and connected clients in separate JDK versions? I'm planning to upgrade ActiveMQ Artemis version to the latest version - `2.29` with JDK `11` and connected clients still with JDK `1.8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to run clients on JDK 1.8 and the broker on JDK 11 (or later).

To be clear, the [latest version](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) at this time is actually 2.30.0, not 2.29.0.